# Separate a column into multiple column in the desired way mentioned

Tags: r, data-manipulation, stringr

I can separate (using ", ") a column into multiple column.

The idea is to reverse the order of words (separated by ", ") and then separate them into multiple columns. Example of reversing - "CA, SF" becomes "SF, CA"

Below is an example

```
library(tidyverse)

# sample example 
tbl <- tibble(
  letter = c("US, CA, SF","NYC", "Florida, Miami")
)

# desired result
tbl_desired <- tibble(
  country = c("US", NA, NA),
  state = c("CA", NA, "Florida"),
  city = c("SF", "NYC", "Miami")
)


# please edit it to get the desired result
tbl %>%
  # please add line to reverse the string
  mutate() %>% 
  separate(letter, into = c("country", "state", "city"), sep = ", ")
```

Comment: Yeah sorry. I thought we need to reverse it to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `fill` argument in `separate` which can be used (by default, it is `"warn"`), but we can change that to either `"right"` or `"left"`.  Here, it should be filled from the "left"

```
library(tidyr)
separate(tbl, letter, into = c("country", "state", "city"), 
     sep = ", ", fill = "left")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
  country state   city 
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>
1 US      CA      SF   
2 <NA>    <NA>    NYC  
3 <NA>    Florida Miami
```